# Strange Integer Characters from VS2010 when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Since a few days when i debugging it shows me strange characters instead of integer values. Its only happen with integers, with string and boolean values shows me correctly.

Is only debugging with a Web Service, is not caused by GET or POST methods by ajax, etc etc

Here is a snapshot of the problem..

http://i.imgbox.com/adkZJTWb.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have turned on 'Hexadecimal Display' by accident: right-click on the hex value (&H0 in your example) and uncheck 'Hexadecimal Display' on the menu.